# How to deal with team members who do not prioritize work-related tasks?

Tags: leadership

As the leader of a small team, I am currently facing a number of challenges in effectively managing my team members. One of the main difficulties I am experiencing is that some team members seem to lack understanding of the significance and importance of the tasks they are assigned.

For example, I recently attempted to schedule a crucial meeting with a highly sought-after expert in a specific field. I was able to secure three possible slots, all within the same week, and made myself available for all of them. I then reached out to one of my team members to inquire about their availability so that they could attend the meeting as well. However, to my surprise, the team member declined to attend, citing a conflicting appointment with their investment advisor, who confirmed the week but not the day and time. So they cannot book any slot because it might conflict with their advisor meeting.

This has left me feeling frustrated and unsure of how to handle this situation.

Comment: Question: Is this a common occurrence? Or has it happened once? It's not clear from your  post if you don't know how to handle this particular situation, or if this is just one example of many similar ones.

Comment: @Bogdan there are many similar ones with this employee and others, which make me believe that I am doing something wrong in the management of my team.

Comment: What are their core working times? Are they supposed to be available, or is it outside their core working hours?

Comment: @Yacine: Just to be sure I understand correctly: a team member rejects a work target because of a personal target? Is his target during work hours? Is the work target during free hours? The answer is hugely different depending on the details.

Comment: Be sure to schedule meetings far enough in advance that folks can either schedule, or reschedule, other necessary meetings around them. Ideally, if it's a recurring meeting, have it in a specific place at a specific time on specific days. Then if folks fail to show up because they didn't manage their own calendars correctly, and they don't have a good excuse for why they missed the meeting, that's their choice and they have to live with the consequences. But remember that not everyone has to be at every meeting, and that meetings should be kept as short, focused, and infrequent as practical

Answer (score 4):

As a leader of the team, your responsibility is to take individuals with individual goals and priorities and move them to a cohesive team that has and supports team goals and priorities. What you are experiencing is likely a sign that you have not yet established a cohesive, high-performing team. As a leader, this is your problem, not an individual on your team. You need to figure out how to evolve your team from an immature one to a mature one.

That does not mean you will never have conflict between a team priority and an individual one but it likely means that those conflicts will be more of an exception.

Establishing a high performing team sometimes means you need to remove an individual who is presenting with signals that (s)he is not likely to blend into the team. The message to you that this person cannot commit to a time slot in an entire week is a "pound sand" type of message. This would likely signal to me that the individual is someone who will not likely conform to the team. I would obviously take this example and compare to other examples. But it is a very weird message for an employee to say to the boss.

In your comment you indicated there are others exhibiting similar behaviors. So while your example is concerning for that one individual, you appear to have a more systemic issue and that root cause would be you.

You may not be ready to lead and you may need more training, coaching, and mentoring to establish your skills. Asking the question here is a start but you need to engage a mentor where you work. Start there.

Answer (score 4):

> How to deal with team members who do not prioritize work-related tasks?

You, as the leader, make their work-related tasks priorities.

When you assign the tasks, you clearly explain to them what level of priority it is and make sure that each member of your team understands this.  Make sure that they also clearly understand the consequences of not following your instructions.

As for the meeting, since the task and meeting are high priorities, you don't ask your members for their availability you tell them that they need to attend the meeting at one of the proposed times.  The fact that they *might* have a scheduling conflict with some other meeting is no excuse to decline your meeting.

If the team members continue with their current behavior, you need to start disciplining them according to your company policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really tough situation and I don't envy you. It can be hard to draw a line with people you work with on a daily basis, unfortunately though, as a team leader it is something that is your duty.

If it's just one or two people most of the time, take time aside for a one-to-one and have an honest conversation about priorities. I will assume your company is on flexi-time, WFH or both, but usually it is in the contract that they do need to attend certain meetings and make it clear that this is not an optional meeting and that you will let them know when meetings are option.

Make sure you are approaching it from a place of understanding -

> I understand that your financial advisor meeting is important but this
> is during office hours and whilst I don't mind you stepping out to
> attend this sort of thing most of the time, you are expected to prioritise work meetings during usual office hours.

If it's a whole team issue, you can have the conversation with the wider team about priorities but make sure you don't single anyone out or use a specific example in that scenario.

If you are ignored or get push back then follow your companies guidelines (verbal warning, written warning etc).

The example you've shown above is quite specific in that they've blocked out the whole week for this meeting that will happen some time, it's worth noting though that if they have booked something in their calender for a certain time, you shouldn't be asking them to prioritise work over that in most cases for example

If I had a meeting with a financial advisor at 3pm next Tuesday, and at the time there is no work meeting in my calender when I booked and I blocked it out in my calender, I would not prioritise a work meeting that came up over that. In this circumstance though, if I was asked to attend a work meeting I would see if it's possible to rearrange my personal one.